# Share geojson files across main app and widget targets

Tags: xcode

I looked around but all the questions ask about saving files at runtime to a shared "folder", what I need instead is to share some `.geojson` files that are part of my Xcode project between my main app target and the widget target.

I tried to use "Target Membership" but this ends up duplicating the files.
I read App Groups can share files but I only found ways to save files into the App Group when the app is running, not at buil-time.

How can I share those `.geojson` files without affecting my app bundle size?